# Unable to install dbus-python. Ninja version error?

Tags: python, ninja, meson-build, dbus-python

I'm trying to build dbus-python from source since I'm unable to install through pip when running `pip3 install dbus-python`:

```
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Once the repo cloned, I run `python3 setup.py build` and get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not detect Ninja v1.8.2 or newer
```

`pip3 list` returns: `ninja 1.10.2.4`

Answer (score 0):

I know that sometimes the issue is fixed, when you reinstall ninja via pip. You could try that.

`pip install --force-reinstall ninja`

Comment: Did not change anything. Already tried reinstalling.